# What do you call a contraption for holding newspapers?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, image-identification

In Austria, there is newspaper holder that looks like this:

[image: Newspaper holder]

This allows you to hold newspapers in a more convenient way:

[image: newspaper holding apparatus]

Is there a better word for this device in American English than *newspaper holder*?

**Sample sentence:**

> In the library, the newspapers were attached to newspaper _______ which made you feel like in a café.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple _newspaper stick_ as suggested in the accepted answer or the more complex device you pictured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [newspaper holding stick](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&biw=768&bih=909&ei=nziJW8CCD-OTlwTssr7YDQ&q=newspaper%20holding%20%20stick%20&oq=newspaper%20holding%20%20stick%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...22065.22939..23659...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1.Sz9hmJAovno&pccc=1#imgrc=o-WEwJHatI0DcM:)

[Newspaper holder](https://www.google.it/search?q=ewspaper%20holders&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=ewspaper%20holders%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6826j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=yaQkrmwrCIqIqM:)  generally refers to different kind of  container where you keep papers and magazines.

Comment: Is this that thing where Google searches are tailored to you and your part of the world (is that real or rumour)? Because the google search shows a newspaper holding stick for me - if I wanted to buy one, I could now.

Comment: The google search for “newspaper holder” is confusing me too. I’m seeing pictures for different types of furniture and some stuff I can’t identify and also what appears to be the same thing asked about in the op. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab8Na.png

Comment: @userr2684291 here's another link [The definition for newspaper stick:
"A sturdy hardwood or metal rod about three feet long, divided lengthwise down the center, usually into four thin shafts, with a handle on one end and a rubber ring at the other to hold the most recent issue of a newspaper securely along the fold. When not in use, the rods are designed to rest horizontally in a rack high enough to allow the leaves to hang freely without touching the floor. Synonymous with newspaper rod."](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english/general-conversation-greetings-letters/1055289-newspaper-cane.html)

Comment: The device the OP referred to is different from a newspaper stick as shown in the answer.  The newspaper stick is just that -- a simple stick -- whereas the OP asked about a more complicated device with a handle offset from the spine and a support mechanism for the paper.

Comment: @user070221 Rather than just a link to a Google search (the results of which are location-dependent), images and references would be more helpful.

Comment: Also, please don't discuss other users in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It appears this is closely if not inseparably linked to Vienna and Viennese coffeehouses.

Hammacher Schlemmer sells them as [Viennese Coffeehouse Newspaper Holders](https://www.hammacher.com/product/viennese-coffeehouse-newspaper-holder).  Zangra also calls them [Newspaper Holders](https://zangra.com/en/p/newspaper-holder-1) and links them directly to Viennese coffehouses.

The travel site Vienna Unwrapped lists them as one of their [top five insider gifts](https://www.vienna-unwrapped.com/what-to-buy-in-vienna/) to buy in Vienna.

So I think the best you can do is ***newspaper holder*** and if you want to explicitly refer to the type shown in your question, go with ***Viennese coffeehouse newspaper holder***.

Comment: They also exist in Italy, it's not exclusive to Vienna, especially popular in cafés/bars.

Comment: Seems like they would be common throughout Europe and anywhere folks enjoy a nice cuppa while reading the paper.  I'm pretty sure I've never seen one in the US.

Comment: They've got the stick/rod version in Berlin, but they aren't nearly as comfortable for reading as I imagine the one in the OP's picture is. (Sometimes it's stapled so you can't read the inner margin.) I think the rod version is more for keeping the newspaper tidy so it's not a mess after the first customer reads it.

Comment: Here in the US, the rod version is used in libraries where people either hold them in both hands or lay them on a table.  Hard to drink coffee, though, while holding a newspaper with both hands and coffee shop tables here are too small to lay out the paper.  Also, coffee shops (in my area) don't usually provide newspapers for customers to read; some will sell them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]As a native of Vienna I'd use *Viennese newspaper holder* (a) which is the literal translation of the German term *Wiener Zeitungshalter*.
Other devices which are not as sophisticated I'd call *newspaper sticks* (b).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. If you provided references and links, your answer would be much improved. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: These terms have already been given in earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to refer to the metal contraption initially pictured I would use ‘paper rack’.

Comment: This would be better with a authoritative source for your chosen term.